# Flex-Layout : Push last item to the end horizontally

Tags: angular-material, angular-flex-layout

Here is what I've done so far :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsmp9l

On the snippet we can see a simple toolbar containing buttons (open the HTML view in a bigger size since there are some `fxShow / fxHide` directives triggering).

What I am trying to do is to push the Login button on the end of the div, far right.

I tried the following :

- Add a `<span style="flex: 1 1 auto;"></span>` between the Login and Contact button
- Add a `style="margin-left: auto;"` to the Login button
- Add `fxFlexFill` to the `div` elements containing the links, and try again with the `span` and `margin-left` as mentionned above
- Looked around for documentation about Flex containers but nothing helps me

If I remove the `div` container and use the `<span style="flex: 1 1 auto;">` it works correctly, the Login buttons appears at the end of the toolbar (horizontally).

I would like to understand why the `div` container causes this behavior and how I could do to have the Login button pushed on the right. Maybe my understanding of Flex containers is not good so any pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try the following:

```html
<div fxFill>
  <!-- ... -->
  <a mat-button routerLink="/contact">Contact</a>
  <span fxFlex></span>
  <a mat-button routerLink="/login">Login</a>
</div>
```

The span with `fxFlex` will fill up all the parent container's space that is not used up by other child elements. That's why the parent container should have `width: 100%`, otherwise it will only be as big as its children need it to be. With Flex-Layout, you can achieve that by using `fxFill`.

Edit:

In the [declarative API docs](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/67e4bf5bccc0adeaf2752d0d38fee465ffeea2fc/docs/documentation/Declarative-API-Overview.md), `fxFill` is listed but does not have any comment. In the [code docs](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/8f591c595765b134e0ff86327c495baa1a5f1821/src/lib/flexbox/api/flex-fill.ts) however, it says:

> 'fxFill' flexbox styling directive
>   Maximizes width and height of element in a layout container
>   NOTE: fxFill is NOT responsive API!!

Comment: I used the `fxFlex` directive for the span and added a `style="100%"` to the parent container. However, I did not find documentation about `fxFill`, any pointers ?

Comment: It's not really described in the docs but something can be found in the source code. See edit

Comment: Okay thank you @Kim Kern, I tried your solution but I had some unintended behavior, like having the Login button again on the left side when I switch from Desktop to Mobile screen size. I finally found a solution by adding the `fxShow / fxHide` directive on each button of my toolbar. But again thank you, I understood this directive better